# How to run a Swift method of a subclass of an Objective-C class, which has a method with the same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**What I had first:**

- I have this method in `JSQMessagesViewController.m`:

  ```
  - (id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      NSAssert(NO, @"ERROR: required method not implemented: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
      return nil;
  }
  ```
- And then `MessagesViewController.swift` with a subclass:

  ```
  class MessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
  ```

  with this method inside:

  ```
  func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
      return messages[messageDataForItemAtIndexPath.item]
  }
  ```
- A controller in the storyboard of class `MessagesViewController`

**The obvious "problem":**

When I run the app I'm getting this error:
`ERROR: required method not implemented: -[JSQMessagesViewController collectionView:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:]'`

So, obviously the method in `JSQMessagesViewController.m`is being called.

**What I've tried to solve it, and the real problems:**

1. Rename the swift method to:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
   ```

   - But I've got: `Method 'collectionView(_:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:)' with Objective-C selector 'collectionView:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:' conflicts with method 'collectionView(_:messageDataForItemAt:)' from superclass 'JSQMessagesViewController' with the same Objective-C selector`
2. Adding then an override prefix to prevent the conflict above:

   ```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
   ```

   - But then I'm getting: `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

**What I want to know:**

1. I want to understand that contradiction between the point 1. (conflict between a method and its superclass same-name-method) and 2. (no superclass method with the same name).
2. To run the code assuming the controller being used is of the class `MessagesViewController` instead of `JSQMessagesViewController` (as that's the class wrote in the Identity inspector), and to call [object collectionView:..., messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:...] using the swift subclass method.

Comment: Why do you have those exclamation marks in the swift function declaration?  The parameters are not implicitly unwrapped optionals. Get rid of those and the function signature should match.

Comment: Those come from the auto-converting function of Xcode. I'll try to remove them and then tell you if there's a difference. This is my first time with Swift. Thank you

Comment: With `func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JSQMessageData {` I got `Method 'collectionView(_:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:)' with Objective-C selector 'collectionView:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:' conflicts with method 'collectionView(_:messageDataForItemAt:)' from superclass 'JSQMessagesViewController' with the same Objective-C selector`

Comment: You need `override`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this definition (Swift 3):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> JSQMessageData {
    // return your item
}
```

I used this in my project almost 6 months ago.

P.S. JSQMessagesViewController is deprecated now and no longer maintained. You can use [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) instead.

P.P.S. You can learn more about how objective-c methods are imported to Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html).